# Output path folders to Data Lake Store without "ColumnName="

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

Is posible to use the function partitionBy or other without returning the path "ColumnName=Value"?

I´m using a python notebook in azure databricks to send a csv file to Azure Data Lake Store. The Cmd used is the following:

```
%scala
val filepath= "dbfs:/mnt/Test"

Sample
  .coalesce(1)       
  .write             
  .mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy("Year","Month","Day")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter",";")
  .csv(filepath)
```

Expecting to have this path:
/Test/2018/12/11

Instead of: 
/Test/Year=2018/Month=12/Day=11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. 
Spark uses directory path for partition with columns names.

If you need specific directory you should use downstream process to rename directory or you can filter your df and save one by one in the specific directory.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a downstream process or other case, please?